# Python Matplotlib slider widget is not updating

Tags: python, slider, matplotlib

i want to use multiple matplotlib canvasses which contain data + a (matplotlib) slider widget.
the problem is that the slider widgets are not updating correctly (looks like the mouse events are not sent or something)

this is what i have:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

class PlotWidget( Tk.Frame ):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=75)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)

        self.frame = self.canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.frame.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.show()

    def add_slider(self):
       a = self.figure.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow')
       s = Slider( a, 'range', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=5)
       self.canvas.show()



root = Tk.Tk()

option = 1    

if option == 1 or option = 2:
     w =  PlotWidget(root)
     w.pack()
     figure = w.figure
else:
     f = Tk.Frame(root, bd = 6, bg='red')
     figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=75)
     canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, f)
     canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
     canvas.show()
     f.pack()


if option = 1:
    w.add_slider()
else:
    a = figure.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow')   
    s = Slider( a, 'range', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=5)

Tk.mainloop()
```

option 1 does not work all other combinations do (in the test script atleast, in my application it also does not work when i create the slider widget in another location.
the slider does not react on the mouse events.....

what am i missing?!

Answer (score 2):

I had to make the following changes to get your script to run on my machine.

```
import matplotlib
from Tkinter import *
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

class PlotWidget( Frame ):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=75)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)

        self.frame = self.canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.show()

    def add_slider(self):
       a = self.figure.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow')
       s = Slider( a, 'range', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=5)
       self.canvas.show()



root = Tk()

option = 1

if option == 1 or option == 2:
     w =  PlotWidget(root)
     w.pack()
     figure = w.figure
else:
     f = Frame(root, bd = 6, bg='red')
     figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=75)
     canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, f)
     canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
     canvas.show()
     f.pack()


if option == 1:
    w.add_slider()
else:
    a = figure.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow')   
    s = Slider( a, 'range', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=5)

root.mainloop()
```

I believe option 1 doesn't work due to the scope of which the Slider is being created in.

The example [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) also creates it in same scope as the figure and show commands.

If you wanted to move the Slider creation into a function you have that function return the Slider back to the scope outside the function, add as the last line of add_slider `return  s` and then change `w.add_slider()` to `s = w.add_slider()`

or you could store the relevant in the same scope (class member) as canvas and figure e.g `self.slider = Slider( a, 'range', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=5)`.

Both of these methods make the slider update on mouse event when `option = 1`.

Comment: i knew it had to be something simple but you are now officially my hero!