# matplotlib - Add sliders to a figure dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, slider

Based on [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069944/add-slider-to-matplotlib-chart) examples, I am trying to add sliders to a figure dynamically (in function of the object that is plotted).

The sliders are created and added inside a for-loop, and a new `update()` function is created every time.

Problems: The sliders do not respond to any mouse inputs!

Any idea how to solve this?

[image: graph]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

    def plot(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.l = plt.plot(obj.t,obj.series())
        vars = obj.get_variables()
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.03*(len(vars)+2))
        for i,var in enumerate(vars):
            self.add_slider(i*0.03, var[0], var[1], var[2])
        plt.show()

    def add_slider(self, pos, name, min, max):
        ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.02+pos, 0.8, 0.02], axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow')
        slider = Slider(ax, name, min, max, valinit=getattr(self.obj, name))
        def update(val):
            setattr(self.obj, name, val)
            self.l.set_ydata(self.obj.series())
            self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        slider.on_changed(update)

class SinFunction:
    def __init__(self):
        self.freq = 1.0
        self.amp = 0.5
        self.t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)

    def series(self):
        return self.amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*self.freq*self.t)

    def get_variables(self):
        return [
            ('freq', 0.1, 10),
            ('amp', 0.1, 1)
        ]

Plotter().plot(SinFunction())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `plot` method of the `Plotter` class you are obtaining all the *series* of the plot in this way `self.l = plt.plot(obj.t,obj.series())` so in `self.l` you have a list of objects and not the object itself. You could have more than one line.

In the `add_slider` method you should change the line `self.l.set_ydata(self.obj.series())` with `self.l[0].set_ydata(self.obj.series())` to use the method of the object. In this case there is only one object in `self.l` but you could have more. Please, take this into account.

Also, to make sliders work accordingly (see comments below) it seems they need to be in the same scope. To have sliders in the same scope you could create a `sliders attribute`

The final code should be:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

    def plot(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.l = plt.plot(obj.t,obj.series())
        _vars = obj.get_variables()
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.03*(len(_vars)+2))
        self.sliders = []
        for i,var in enumerate(_vars):
            self.add_slider(i*0.03, var[0], var[1], var[2])
        plt.show()

    def add_slider(self, pos, name, min, max):
        ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.02+pos, 0.8, 0.02], axisbg='lightgoldenrodyellow')
        slider = Slider(ax, name, min, max, valinit=getattr(self.obj, name))
        self.sliders.append(slider)
        def update(val):
            setattr(self.obj, name, val)
            self.l[0].set_ydata(self.obj.series())
            self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        slider.on_changed(update)

class SinFunction:
    def __init__(self):
        self.freq = 1.0
        self.amp = 0.5
        self.t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)

    def series(self):
        return self.amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*self.freq*self.t)

    def get_variables(self):
        return [
            ('freq', 0.1, 10),
            ('amp', 0.1, 1)
        ]

k = Plotter()
k.plot(SinFunction())
```

This version is working for me on Python 2 and Python 3.

P.D.: I saw different behaviour on Python 2 when compared with Python 3. I don't know if it is something related with Python or with Matplotlib... ¿?

Comment: Thank you! However, this does not resolve the original problem (the non-responsive sliders). Any clue on that?

Comment: It is working for me. Please, could you tell me how are you running the code, what errors are you obtaining, library versions,...?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.4.3, and I am running the script from a IPython notebook.

Comment: Do you want the plots to be embedded inside the notebook or as an independent window?

Comment: I'm fine with a window

Comment: so use `%matplotlib qt` mode (just type that in a cell). I think you have setted `%matplotlib inline` or other mode and it is not working. Other way to add interactive plots inside the notebook itself would be to use the `ipywidgets` package (https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/)

Comment: I figured it out thanks to that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336822/python-matplotlib-slider-widget-is-not-updating 
It's a problem of scope: `add_slider()` needs to return the slider. Feel free to update your answer: I'll upvote & accept.

Comment: I updated the code. I saw some weird behavior when changing from Py2 to Py3. I have the same matplotlib version on both Python versions. I think the code now is working on Py2 and Py3.